# how to draw the lines outside the axis in Flutter CustomPaint

Tags: flutter, flutter-custompainter

I have a `Container` with a `CustomPaint` as the parent. In the `CustomPaint` I just draw a line on the half surrounding of the `Container`. The line is drawn with half of its width inside the `Container` and the other half outside the `Container`. I want to draw the line completely outside of the `Container`. How can I achieve this behavior? Thanks in advance.

Here's how it looks like now:
[image]

Here's my code:

```
Center(
        child: CustomPaint(
          painter: SeatDecorator(),
          child: Container(
            width: 150,
            height: 150,
            color: Colors.blue.withOpacity(0.5),
          ),
        ),
      )
```

My CustomPainter:

```
class SeatDecorator extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    Paint paint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.blue
      ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.square
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeJoin = StrokeJoin.round
      ..strokeWidth = 8;

    Path path = Path();
    path.moveTo(0, size.height / 2);
    path.lineTo(0, 0);
    path.lineTo(size.width, 0);
    path.lineTo(size.width, size.height / 2);
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: Seems like you could make a Rect from your corners, and then use Rect.inflate with half your stroke width to get the new corner points.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz Can you please write your solution in code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stroke center uses the last point to draw on canvas, you can count half of the `strokeWidth` while positioning lines.

```
class SeatDecorator extends CustomPainter {
  SeatDecorator({this.strokeWidth = 8});
  final double strokeWidth;
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    Paint paint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.blue
      ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.square
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeJoin = StrokeJoin.round
      ..strokeWidth = strokeWidth;

    Path path = Path();
    final halfStrokeWidth = strokeWidth / 2;
    path.moveTo(-halfStrokeWidth, size.height / 2);
    path.lineTo(-halfStrokeWidth, -halfStrokeWidth);
    path.lineTo(size.width + halfStrokeWidth, -halfStrokeWidth);
    path.lineTo(size.width + halfStrokeWidth, size.height / 2);
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant SeatDecorator oldDelegate) => oldDelegate.strokeWidth != strokeWidth;
}
```

You can use ShapeBorder for cases like this.

Answer (score 0):

I'll leave my answer here to help someone that is using Rects or RRects. I solved my problem using the `deflate` method on it. The parameter would be half of the stroke width.

```
canvas
      ..drawRRect(rRect,
          Paint()..color = color
      ..drawRRect(
        rRect.deflate(strokeWidth / 2),
        Paint()
          ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round
          ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
          ..color = borderColor
          ..strokeWidth = strokeWidth,
      );
```